# infija a posfija

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas con el codigo de typescript se trata de cambiar una operacion de infija a posfija.

```
var boton = document.querySelector("button");

var dato: any;
var Larray: number;


boton.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    dato = document.getElementById("dato").value;
    dato = Array.from(dato);

    Larray = dato.length;

    a.dato = dato;
    a.operacion();

    console.log(a);
});

class PostFijo {
    public dato: Array<any>;

    public operacion(){
        var derecha, izquierda, operador: string;
        var resultado: number;

        for (let i = 0; i <= Larray; i++) {
            if(dato[i] == "0" || dato[i] == "1" || dato[i] == "2" || dato[i] == "3" || dato[i] == "4" || dato[i] == "5" || 
                dato[i] == "6" || dato[i] == "7" || dato[i] == "8" || dato[i] == "9"){

                if(izquierda ==  null){
                    izquierda = dato[i];
                }

                if(operador != null){      <----- Aquí esta el problema, no entra
                    derecha = dato[i];
                    dato.push(operador);
                }
            }

            if(dato[i] == "+" || dato[i] == "-" || dato[i] == "*" || dato[i] == "/" || dato[i] == "%" || dato[i] == "^"){
                operador = dato[i];
                dato[i] = dato.pop();
                
            }
        }
    }

}

var a = new PostFijo();
```

El problema esta en que no entra en ese if que marque en el código, al ponerle un console.log(derecha) no me muestra la variable por lo que deduje que no estaba entrando, cheque si realmente el **operador** si contiene algo para que entrara en ese if y si, lo tiene es un "+" por lo tanto en el tercer ciclo que hace del for debería de entrar pero no lo hace.

intuí que tenia algo que ver con la longitud del array por lo que lo cambie por una variable que tuviera dicha longitud llamada **Larray** para que cuando se haga el **pop** no cambie la longitud y por ende me saque antes, pero tampoco era eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podriamos ayudarte pero no me queda claro lo de infija y posfija que tal si nos explica mejor

Comment: Ayudaría también el ver un ejemplo de entrada y la salida que esperas. Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en la forma en que manejas los datos de entrada. Deseas cambiar una entrada que tiene notación infija, a [notación polaca inversa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_polaca_inversa) (notación posfija). De tal forma que si el usuario ingresa por ejemplo:

```
2 + 2
```

El resultado debe ser:

```
2 2 +
```

Ahora, la implementación que muestras es bastante básica, pero se puede mejorar. Uno de los desafíos es el manejo de las cantidades ingresadas y el determinar si la operación representada por la entrada es válida o no lo es.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Debemos partir por definir lo que significa una [notación infija](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_de_infijo): es aquella en la que se escriben los operadores entre los operandos que actúan en la operación, a diferencia de la notación de posfijo (Notación Polaca Inversa) en la que se escriben los operandos en el orden de aparición y de último se escribe el operador que actúa sobre los mismos.

Para resolver el problema, debemos analizar la cadena de entrada. En tu código haces una serie de operaciones para intentar analizar la cadena:

```js
let dato = '2 + 2'
dato = Array.from(dato);
console.log(dato);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Luego intentas recorrer el `array` esperando determinar tanto los operandos como los operadores.

Tienes:

```
// declaración de variables
var derecha, izquierda, operador: string;

//recorrido del array
for (let i = 0; i <= Larray; i++) {
  //primera comparación
  if(dato[i] == "0" || dato[i] == "1" || ... || dato[i] == "9") { // esto no es necesario
    // segunda comparación
    if(izquierda ==  null){
      izquierda = dato[i];
    }
    // tercera comparación
    if(operador != null){
      derecha = dato[i];
      dato.push(operador);
    }
  //...
}
```

Claramente esta forma de analizar la cadena de entrada no es la más adecuada. Para empezar, cuando creas las variables sin asignarles un valor, su valor por defecto será siempre `undefined`. Y si bien, cuando escribes en JS (o Typescript en este caso) algo como:

```
> undefined == null
> true
```

Sin embargo, no es recomendable realizar una comparación tan ligera y es preferible usar una comparación estricta, en la cual:

```
> undefined === null
> false
```

Otra forma de probar si una variable no es ni `undefined` ni `null` es pasar la misma directamente dentro de un contexto booleano, sin usar una comparación contra `null` o `undefined`

```js
var tengoValor;

if(!tengoValor) {
  console.log('La variable es undefined');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esto es porque en JS (por lo tanto en Typescript) existen valores llamados [`falsy` o `falsey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), que devuelven `false` en un contexto booleano. Tanto `null` como `undefined` son valores `falsy`.

Ahora, volviendo a la forma en que analizas o pretendes analizar la cadena de entrada, podemos hacer unas cuantas modificaciones.

Primero, al usar `Array.from()` sobre una cadena, cada carácter de la cadena se convertirá en un elemento de nuestro `Array`, como ya pudimos ver con anterioridad, por lo tanto los espacios en blanco también serán parte de nuestro `Array`, lo cual implica iteraciones adicionales.

Una forma de solucionar este inconveniente es utilizar el método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) del tipo `String` y usar una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp) para determinar el separador de entre los operadores aritméticos básicos. También podemos hacer uso del método [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) para eliminar los espacios en blanco que pudieran existir en la cadena recibida.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let dato = "2 + 2";
let opRegex = /[(+)?(\-)?(*)?(\/)?]/;

let operandos = dato.split(operadores).map(operando => operando.trim());

console.log(operandos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora ya tenemos un `Array` de operandos y sólo nos hace falta emparejar los mismos con cada operador que existiese entre cada par de operandos.

Para ello podemos crear un segundo `Array` para filtrar aquellos operadores.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let dato = "2 + 2";
let opRegex = /[(+)?(\-)?(*)?(\/)?]/g;

let operandos = dato.split(opRegex).map(operando => operando.trim());
console.log('Operandos:')
console.log(operandos);

let operadores = dato.match(opRegex);

console.log('Operadores');
console.log(operadores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos los ladrillos necesarios para construir nuestra expresión en notación de posfijo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const posFijo = infijo => {
  if(!infijo) return;
  
  let opRegex = /[(+)?(\-)?(*)?(\/)?]/g;

  let operandos = infijo.split(opRegex).map(operando => operando.trim());
  let operador = infijo.match(opRegex);
  // comprobamos que infijo es válido
  if(operandos.length !== 2) return;
  if(operador.length !== 1) return;
  // ahora podemos construir el posfijo
  let posfijo = [...operandos, operador].join(' ');
  return posfijo;
}

console.log(posFijo('2 + 2')); // 2 2 +
console.log(posFijo('32 * 25')); // 32 25 *
console.log(posFijo('2 + 2 -')); // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, esto sólo funciona para una expresión con 1 operador y 2 operandos. Podemos extenderlo para casos más generales, como por ejemplo, dada la siguiente expresión:

```
3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ^ 2 ^ 3
```

Se espera que la salida en notación de posfijo (RPN) sea la siguiente:

```
3 4 2 * 1 5 - 2 3 ^ ^ / +
```

Para este caso, se utilizan algoritmos más avanzados, como el algoritmo de [*Shunting-yard*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_shunting_yard), el cuál está fuera del alcance de la pregunta original.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: No me esperaba una respuesta tan detallada, muchas gracias la verdad, el `arrray.from` es porque me lo pidieron a través de una interfaz entonces al llegar los datos me llegaban en forma de **String** y quería convertirlos en **Elementos de un Array** para poderlos utilizar. Y también voy a ocupar el shuting-yard gracias